# Using CSS to zoom on an image on hover but maintain the image size. I got it to work, but it's only displaying one corner of the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an image near the top of a webpage. I've made it so that when I hover on the image, it zooms in slightly. However, in doing so, I've messed something up that causes the image to only display one portion whether hover is activated or not. I've tried removing portions of the code I added, but can't seem to fix it without completely removing the hover animation. I've also tried changing margin, padding, and position. I'm using Bootstrap 4 if that makes a difference. I'm sure it's something simple, I just can't seem to figure out what needs to be changed.

Here's a link to the Codepen: https://codepen.io/amandathedev/pen/zyEyze

Here's the relevant portion of the CSS:

```
.imgBox {
float: left;
position: relative;
width: 640px;
height: 360px;
margin: 0 auto;
/* justify-content: center;
display: inline-block; */
overflow: hidden;
}

.imgCard {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.imgCard img {
-webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
transition: 0.4s ease;
}

.imgBox:hover .imgCard img {
  transform: scale(1.05);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code example on codepen, the solution looks to be making the width of the img 100%. So in your example you would do something like:

```
.photo {
    width:100%
}
```

However, this cuts off the bottom of the image. You're going to need to adjust the height of the imgBox that contains the imgCard. It's currently set to 360px. Because of the way your example is written, it will probably be best for you to just choose a number so that the resulting image will have the same aspect ratio as the original image (playing around with it, 478px looks like the magic number to show the entire image).

Comment: Ahh, that did it! Thank you so much for your help; I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set transform-origin to center so that it will scale from center on, so your css must look like this:

..other css

```
.imgBox:hover .imgCard img {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    transform-origin: center;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't seem to fix it. I copied it over and nothing has changed.

Comment: Is this what you mean ? @AmandaTreutler

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPGVdG

Comment: Not exactly. I'm trying to keep the image within the same dimensions on hover. So like this: https://codepen.io/kanishkkunal/pen/emdxLm?editors=1100  This is the codepen I was using to help me make mine.

Comment: is this what it is ?
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GPGVdG

@AmandaTreutler